# Update query C# SQL server radio button

Tags: c#, sql-server

This update query isn't working when clicking the button. Here Group is the radio button but the program is throwing an excption

```
private void editAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\phoneBookwin\phoneBookwin\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    string value;
    bool friendCheck = newFriends.Checked;
    bool familyCheck = newFamily.Checked;
    bool emergencyCheck = newEmergency.Checked;
    bool collCheck = newColl.Checked;
    if (friendCheck)
        value = newFriends.Text;
    else if (familyCheck)
        value = newFamily.Text;
    else if (emergencyCheck)
        value = newEmergency.Text;
    else if (collCheck)
        value = newColl.Text;
    else
        value = "";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand Command = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        Command.CommandText = " update Contacts set Name =@newName, Contacts = @newNumber, Email = @newEmail, Group = @newGroup where Name = @changeName"; 
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newName",newName.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newNumber", newNumber.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newEmail", newEmail.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newGroup", value);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@changeName", changeName.Text);
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    this.Hide();
    
    Form1 save = new Form1();
    save.ShowDialog();
}
```

Exception thrown

> 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.'

Comment: isn't `group` a keyword in sql server ? Have you tried with `[group]` ?

Comment: @GuidoG Posting just a link with the comment "read this" is not particularly useful; some people are hesitant to follow a link without any information. Suggest you write "don't use addwithvalue ... " rather than just the equivalent of "click here".

Comment: @SMor Fair enough. After I wrote the comment I also wrote an answer that includes the same link again. I should have removed the comment after that, but I forgot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap keyword "Group" with square brackets in your SQL query:

```
update Contacts 
set Name =@newName, Contacts = @newNumber, Email = @newEmail, [Group] = @newGroup 
where Name = @changeName
```

Answer (score 1):

As I already wrote in my comment here, first you should use square brackets for the keyword `group`

```
Command.CommandText = " update Contacts set [Group] = @newGroup, Name =@newName, Contacts = @newNumber, Email = @newEmail where Name = @changeName";
```

Second, avoid `AddWithValue` is has some problems as explained [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

replace

```
Command.Parameters.Add(new AddWithValue("@newName",newName.Text);
```

with this

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@newName", SqlDbType.VarChar)      
  { Value = (newName.Text == "") ? (object)DBNull.Value : newName.Text });
```